# How to get the selected object in a Syncfusion chart?

Tags: uwp, syncfusion

Syncfusion charts support the selection of data items in their charts (see [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/uwp/sfchart/interactive-features#selection)). There is also an event that fires once the selection changes.

I have a list of `TransactionEntry` objects bound to a chart, which include information like `Amount`, `Date` (which are bound to the chart) and several other metadata.

I'm trying access the objects in the changed event to get to the meta data. The `ChangedEvent` args expose a property called `NewPointInfo` (see [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/uwp/Syncfusion.SfChart.UWP~Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Charts.ChartBase~SelectionChanged_ev.html)), which is of the type object. When debugging, I can see that this object is actually a `ChartDataPointInfo` object, which also includes a `NewItem` property which is exactly the object I'm looking for.

Now my problem is that I can't cast the `NewPointInfo` object to the `ChartDataPointInfo` type, because of the protection level of `ChartDataPointInfo`. This type is also not documented by Syncfusion, so I suppose I'm not meant to use this type?

**My question is now:** how do I get access to the underlying `TransactionEntry` object from the `SelectionChanged` event? Can I use the `NewPointInfo` for that and if yes: how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not currently at a development PC to try it out, but I would suggest trying to investigate the [`SelectedSegment` property](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/uwp/Syncfusion.SfChart.UWP~Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Charts.ChartSelectionChangedEventArgs~SelectedSegment.html) of `ChartSelectionChangedEventArgs`.

This is of type [`ChartSegment`](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/uwp/Syncfusion.SfChart.UWP~Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Charts.ChartSegment_members.html) which has a property `Item` which, if I am not mistaken, should be set to the underlying collection item you are looking for. As docs say:

> **Item** -  Gets or sets the data object that this segment belongs to.

Comment: This was almost the solution. The item property is not a single item, but rather the whole list. But together with the selectedIndex property you can get the actually selected item. But the list in the item property is a List<object>, so it needs to be converted first ... But thanks for the pointer in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You can access your object with :

```
(e.SelectedSegment.Item as List<object>)?[e.SelectedIndex] as YourObject
```

Or, more easily :

```
(e.NewPointInfo as ChartSegment).Item as YourObject
```

The problem is that you tried to cast e.NewPointInfo to ChartDataPointInfo, which is an internal class. ChartSegment is the parent class of ChartDataPointInfo, is accessible, and is the one actually containing the Item attribute.